# biblatex: only track citation of a certain type/category

Tags: biblatex

At the moment, `biblatex's`various citation trackers are global and cannot be set on entry type or category level. What I want to achieve is that the things like the `ibidtracker` or the `loccittracker` only track certain entry types or categories.

Consider the following example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@movie{Abrams.JJ:2015,
    Address = {USA},
    Author = {Abrams, J.J.},
    Subtitle = {Star Wars: Episode VII – Das Erwachen der Macht},
    Title = {Star Wars: The Force Awakens},
    Year = {2015}}
@incollection{Abramov.N:2006a,
    Address = {Jackson},
    Author = {Abramov, Naum},
    Booktitle = {Andrei Tarkovsky : Interviews},
    Editor = {Gianvito, John},
    Origdate = {1970},
    Pages = {32--37},
    Publisher = {University Press of Mississippi},
    Series = {Conversations with Filmmakers},
    Title = {Dialogue with Andrei Tarkovsky about Science-Fiction on the Screen},
    Year = {2006}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[%
style=fiwi
,yearatbeginning
,backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite[]{Abramov.N:2006a}
\citefilm{Abrams.JJ:2015}
\cite[]{Abramov.N:2006a}
\end{document}
```

Since there is an entry between the two instances of `\cite{Abramov.N:2006a}` I get the full entry both time. This is correct behaviour, but since the item quoted in between is a film, there is little danger of confusion. So what I want is the tracker to ignore entrys of the type `movie`, so that I get the following output:

> Abramov 2006 Star Wars: The Force Awakens (2015) ebd.

If it makes it makes it easier, I can also live with a solution which makes of categories instead of entry types.

Somehow I thought I had this already running once, but this is obviously not true.

Answer (score 2):

It's relatively easy to disable the trackers for certain entrytypes, but I wouldn't recommend that you do it. First, you will likely confuse your readers, even thought you trust they will not go looking for "Star Wars, p. 15". Second, by disabling the trackers for certain entrytypes, you won't get ibid. etc for them, even if they are cited in sequence. But if you really want it, you can go with:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifentrytype{movie}{\citetrackerfalse}{}}
```

A full MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@movie{Abrams.JJ:2015,
    Address = {USA},
    Author = {Abrams, J.J.},
    Subtitle = {Star Wars: Episode VII – Das Erwachen der Macht},
    Title = {Star Wars: The Force Awakens},
    Year = {2015}}
@incollection{Abramov.N:2006a,
    Address = {Jackson},
    Author = {Abramov, Naum},
    Booktitle = {Andrei Tarkovsky : Interviews},
    Editor = {Gianvito, John},
    Origdate = {1970},
    Pages = {32--37},
    Publisher = {University Press of Mississippi},
    Series = {Conversations with Filmmakers},
    Title = {Dialogue with Andrei Tarkovsky about Science-Fiction on the Screen},
    Year = {2006}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[%
style=fiwi
,yearatbeginning
,backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifentrytype{movie}{\citetrackerfalse}{}}
\begin{document}
\cite[]{Abramov.N:2006a}

\citefilm{Abrams.JJ:2015}

\citefilm{Abrams.JJ:2015}

\cite[]{Abramov.N:2006a}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was looking for something more subtle where the citetracker is not completely turned off. Normally, `biblatex-fiwi` wouldn't display the year of the movie at subsequent quoting. With your solution, this is turned off.

Comment: I suppose you'd like to have a whole parallel tracker for the "nontracked" entrytypes. I'd say if you try to think more systematically on how this "subtle" tracker should behave, you'll probably reach the conclusion that it is as the current tracker does. However, I see your point, and if you'd like to intervene manually on one citation you don't like, you could try `\AtNextCite{\citetrackerfalse}`.

Comment: Indeed, ideally I would be able to define different trackers for various entry types or categories. I realise that this is an overkill for must users, but it's something which would be really useful for me.

Comment: The problem is that, AFAIK, within biblatex, the tests `\ifciteseen`, `\ifciteibid`, `\ifciteidem`, `\ifopcit`, `\ifloccit` all hang on the same `citetracker`. Furthermore, if you defined new trackers, you would have to specify how the two set of trackers would interact with each other. Anyway, my abilities are not up to this task. Perhaps someone else can handle it, or can see another simpler way through this that I can't.